# Create txt file in PHP

Tags: php

I am creating text file in php, file has created in correct format from local pc and if i am trying online then no line break is there and not displaying formated.

I am using this code.

```
header("Content-type: application/txt");
header("Content-Length: ". sizeof($content));
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=". $file);
print $content; die;
```

If anyone have solutions please share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have already tried this "text/plain" but not display correct.

Comment: do you want to display the file in the browser or prompt for download?

Answer (score 6):

you have a typo:

```
header("Content-Length: ". sizeof($content));
```

also, you should use

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
readfile($file);
```

This should be sufficient to send the file as plaintext. If this doesnt work for you for some obscure reason, a last resort would be to wrap the content in `<pre>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

- The correct content type is `text/plain`
- It's `Content-Length`, not `Content-Lenght`, and normally PHP will send this for you
- Instead of `die`, better use `exit`.

The problem is probably because of the wrong MIME type - some browsers will ignore invalid content types and display it as HTML.

Comment: 'This language construct is equivalent to exit()' - from die man page... why use exit()?

Comment: I was under the impression that `die` signals an error, as in, you stop execution immediately because something went wrong, whereas `exit` means you stop execution immediately because you're done with whatever it is you want to do. Technically they're the same, but intuitively, I'd say they signal different intentions.

Comment: Sorry spelling mistake here. It is correct in code "Content-Lenght".

Answer (score 1):

Try this

$content = str_replace("\n\r","\n",$content);

$content = str_replace("\r","\n",$content);

header("Content-type: text/plain");

header("Content-Length: ". sizeof($content));

header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=". $file);

print $content; die;